# XML serialization and encoded attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize an XML with the following element with .NET XmlSerializer :

```
<SomeElement Foo_x003a_Bar="123"/>
```

In the target class, there's the following declaration:

```
class SomeElement
{
    //...
    [XmlAttribute("Foo_x003a_Bar")]
    public string Foo_Bar;
}
```

The attribute is not being read from XML. In the `UnknownAttribute` event handler, I see that `Foo_x003a_Bar` is not recognized, and the list of valid attributes (`Args.ExpectedAttributes`) instead includes `Foo_x005F_x003a_Bar`.

What's the deal here, please? 0x5F is the code for the undescore character. Other attributes in the same element/class with names that contain `_x0020_` deserialize properly. Why does `_x003a_` get some kind of a special treatment?

EDIT: dirty hackery in the form of search/replacing in the XML string before it's parsed helps. But still.

EDIT2: the functions that implement this kind of encoding are `XmlConvert:EncodeName`, `XmlConvert:EncodeLocalName`. The latter handles colons, the former doesn't. Looks like they're calling `EncodeName`...

**EDIT3: [filed a bug report with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1518227). Please navigate there and click "I can too" if you can, too :)**

Comment: Maybe it's treated different because \_x003a\_ is the code for : (colon)

Comment: 20 is the code for space. Both are off limits for attribute names IIRC. Still, the whole thing smells of a double-encoding bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are right about [the treatment](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/dae14279dd0672adead5de00ac8f117dcf74c184/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlReflectionImporter.cs#L195) for `_x<char-code>_` element names (described [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/results/4/XEP/symbol.pdf)), which uses `XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName`.

Given that you've instantiated your `XmlSerializer` using the only the type argument, the namespace is [assumed to be empty](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/dae14279dd0672adead5de00ac8f117dcf74c184/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs#L177).

What should work in your case is to simply use the decoded element names in your `XmlAttributeAttribute` settings:

```cs
class SomeElement
{
    //...
    [XmlAttribute("Foo:Bar")]
    public string Foo_Bar;
}
```

One important factor here is casing, the XML node needs to have `<Foo_x003A_Bar>`, with a capital **A**.

The encoded node name needs to be consistent with XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName:

```cs
XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName("Foo:Bar")
// Foo_x003A_Bar
```